# Value of global variable won't change

Tags: vb.net, global-variables, scope

I have a variable whose scope needs to be global, because it needs to be called in a function as well as in a button press. So I declared the variable in a Module so it would be global.

The problem is that the value of this variable needs to be equal to the value of the text property of a textbox in the form.

Here you can download the VB.net demonstration of my problem: http://db.tt/DDxQJDXl

Below is an explanation of what happens

You enter a string into the textbox, in this case I entered "Hello". Then you click the button and it displays what you wrote.

[image]

You click OK in that message box and change the value in the textbox. In this case I changed it to "Goodbye". Then I hit the button again, but the variable did not change values and the messagebox displays "Hello" again.

[image]

Here is the entire source code:

```
Module Module1
     Public strDataValue = frmTest.txtDataValue.Text
End Module
Public Class frmTest
    Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
        MsgBox(strDataValue)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note:** This is just a demonstration of a problem I'm having in a much larger program so the variable *does* have to be global.

Comment: Just a side-note: Global variables and hungarian notation are very 80s. And they can behave pretty strangely when not handled correctly, just like in this case. I'd grab a good book about object-oriented principles.

Comment: What happens if you add strDataValue = frmTest.txtDataValue.Text before the MsgBox(strDataValue) line?

Comment: @DennisTraub Are there any you suggest?

Comment: Global Variables are necessary to do a lot of things. I don't know how to avoid using them. Also, hungarian notation makes it easier to identify variables when there is a lot of them, I don't care if it's out of style =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the value of the field to the new value in the `TextBox`:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    strDataValue = txtDataValue.Text
    MsgBox(strDataValue)
End Sub
```

The field will not change values by itself.

Comment: You must update your answer: this line - `strDataValue = frmTest.txtDataValue.Text` you need to remove `frmTest.` because the button is in the same form as txtDataValue errors pop up if you specify the form. So just change that line to`strDataValue = txtDataValue.Text`

Answer (score 3):

The value of strDataValue won't automatically change when txtDataValue.Text changes. You need to update strDataValue manually, either when the textbox loses focus, or when you click the Test button.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a public property, which automatically returns the actual value as long as the form is open.

```
Public ReadOnly Property DataValue() As String
    Get
        Return frmTest.txtDataValue.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value of `txtDataValue.Text` to your variable `strDataValue` in better performance

Using of **Timer** object or ***TextChenged*** event not recommended

Any change of `txtDataValue.Text` can assign after end of editing action

for me best solution: `Leave` or `LostFocus` events

```
Private Sub txtDataValue_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDataValue.Leave
       strDataValue = txtDataValue.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this would be a good solution if it was necessary to force update the value, but I don't. I just set the value to be automatically updated when the button is clicked. I will give you comment an upvote